# Python: Can you dynamically get the amount of variables a function is going to return into?

Tags: python, input, count, return, args

Part of a utility system my AcecoolLib package I'm writing by porting all / most of my logic to Python, and other various languages, on contains a simple, but greatly useful helper... a function named ENUM.

It has many useful features, such as automatically creating maps of the enums, extended or reverse maps if you have the map assigned to more than just values, and a lot more.

It can create maps for generating function names dynamically, it can create simple maps between enumeration and text or string identifiers for language, and much more.

The function declaration is simple, too:

```
def ENUM( _count = None, *_maps ):
```

It has an extra helper... Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gzi44i7dh58v61/dynamic_properties_accessorfuncs_and_more.py?dl=0

The other one isn't used. `ENUM_MAP` is, but the other isn't.

Anyway, before I start going into etc.. etc.. the question is:

How can I count the return variables outside of the function... ie:

```
ENUM_EXAMPLE_A, ENUM_EXAMPLE_B, ENUM_EXAMPLE_C, ENUM_LIST_EXAMPLE, MAP_ENUM_EXAMPLE = ENUM( None, [ '#example_a', '#example_b', '#example_c' ] )
```

Where List is a simple list of `0 = 0, 1 = 1, 2 = 2`, or something. , then the map links so `[ 0 = '#example_a', 1 = '#example_b', etc.. ]`, then `[ '#example_a' = 0, etc.. ]` for reverse... or something along those lines.

There are other advanced use cases, not sure if I have those features in the file above, but regardless... I'm trying to simply count the return vars... and get the names.

I know it is likely possible, to read the line from which the call is executed... read the file, get the line, break it apart and do all of that... but I'm hoping something exists to do that without having to code it from scratch in the default Python system...

in short: I'd like to get rid of the first argument of `ENUM( _count, *_maps )` so that only the optional `*_maps` is used. So if I call: `ENUM_A, ENUM_B, ENUM_C, LIST_ENUMS = ENUM( );` it'll detect 4 output returns, and get the name of them so I can see if the last contains certain text different from the style of the first... ie, if they want the list, etc.... If they add a map, then optional list, etc.. and I can just count back n _maps to find the list arg, or not...

I know it probably isn't necessary, but I want it to be easy and dynamic so if I add a new enum to a giant list, I don't have to add the number ( although for those I use the maps which means I have to add an entry anyway )...

Either way - I know in Lua, this is stupid easy to do with built-in functions.. I'm hoping Python has built in functions to easily grab the data too.

Thanks!

Comment: A quick comment - to simplify the 'ask'...

Comment: A quick comment - if I don't have to rewrite it because hitting the wrong key deleted everything.... I'd like to create A, B, C = ENUM( ); and it returns 0, 1, 2 into A, B, C without anything more or less. Or: A, B, C, LIST_ABC and return 0, 1, 2, [ 0 = 0, 1 = 1 2 = 2 ], or A, B, C, LIST_ABC, MAP_ABC, MAPR_ABC = ENUM( { '#a', '#b', '#c' } ) and return 0, 1, 2, [ 0 = 0, 1 = 1 2 = 2 ], [ 0 = '#a', 1 = '#b' 2 = '#c' ], [ '#a = 0', '#b' = 1 '#c' = 2 ] ----- IE: for the times when _maps are included, this is easy. But if () is used, I want to count how many args are expected by the caller, and name

Comment: how many args are expected by the caller, and the names of the args as string / text... This would let me se when someone transitions between enums to list, if they even want a list or just enums, etc... for maps it would let me then see if they want a list etc... in short, it'd make it more useful and easier to use for new developers ( I teach other languages and am trying to extend my knowledge, always. ).. -- -- The comment deleted everything then had to retype and could no longer edit. also ran out of room... Last part first..

Comment: If you have more details to add, put them in the question, not comments.

Comment: could you think about moving to using the standard `enum` module?  having to keep the two lists in sync looks somewhat error prone in your method

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can't.

In Python when you do `(a, b, c) = func()` it's called tuple unpacking.  Essentially it's expecting `func()` to return a `tuple` of exactly 3 elements (in this example).  However, you can also do `a = func()` and then `a` will contain a 3-element tuple or whatever `func` decided to return.  Regardless of how `func` is called, there's nothing within the method that knows how the return value is going to be processed after it's returned.

I wanted to provide a more pythonic way of doing what you're intending, but I'm not really sure I understand the purpose of `ENUM()`.  It seems like you're trying to create constants, but Python doesn't really have true constants.

EDIT:

Methods are only aware of what's passed in as arguments.  If you want some sort of ENUM to value mapping then the best equivalent is a dict.  You could then have a method that took `ENUM('A', 'B', 'C')` and returned `{'A':0, 'B':1, 'C':2}` and then you'd use dict look-ups to get the values.

```py
enum = ENUM('A', 'B', 'C')
print(enum['A'])  # prints 0
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of unpacking and use it quite frequently as it is useful.

Comment: I'm creating 'constants', but also enumeration. The difference is a constant is meant to hold a value, such as the constant C in math, the speed of light. or an AU or Astronomical Unit. These are USEFUL bits of data which can be used as is. An enumerated value means the value has no meaning, other than it is different. An Enum gives meaning to the variable name. ie: It lets you do something like if ( _filetype = FILETYPE_MOVIE ){...} instead of doing something like if _filetype = 0.. then link 0 to avi, mp4, mkv, etc.. or other examples. The result is the code becomes more human readable

Comment: I hope that clarifies the difference of an ENUM value, and a CONSTant. Constants are useful for the variable name and value as it makes the code more human readable, while also having mathematical, or other, meaning. The enum is a placeholder so you don't have to hard-code hard-to-read stuff which you may not remember what it was later on. -- It doesn't matter if Python doesn't have 'true' const / enum definitions, but they can still be used as the idea exists, and it is quite helpful for creating easily maintainable code.

Comment: Also, does your 'simple answer' state there is no internal method, or are you saying that it is impossible in Python? If you mean the latter, then there are always ways to create new features and I would be able to create it - but I'm hoping there is an internal method which wouldn't be as 'costly' to execute as file i/o. - Cheers.

Comment: ie: since the feature wouldn't provide a ground-breaking advantage to having it, other than automatically generating enum values based on data... cost of file i/o is too high, to integrate in the way I'm thinking of. I'll try playing around with the stack / trace functionality to see if I can find some type of information - but, as I assume you said, it may not exist by default.

Comment: In one of my comments: "I'm creating 'constants', but also enumeration." -- Should read: I do create / use 'constants', in addition to enumeration. -- Also, one of my ENUM functions does allow for creating a bitwise style of progression. - the value still 'means' nothing, but can easily be combined and separated. Much like chmod..

Comment: I added an 'EDIT' that is the best solution I can think of...

Comment: Also - the simple answer is you can. In coding, anything is possible. But there doesn't appear to be a built-in method of doing so. -- meaning, in order to do it, you have to use debug tracing to see which file, line, etc.. called the function, and then read the data into memory, and parse it to see what is trying to be returned. So, it is possible, but there isn't a built-in method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one proposed answer, similar to what I could do in my Lua framework... The difference, though, is my framework has to load all of the files into memory ( for dynamic reloading, and dynamic changes, going to the appropriate location - and to network the data by combining everything so the file i/o cost is 'averted' - and Lua handles tables incredibly well ).

The simple answer, is that it is possible.. I'm not sure about in default Python without file i/o, however this method would easily work. This answer will be in pseudo context - but the functionality does exist.

**Logic:**

**1)** Using traces, you can determine which file / path and which line, called the ENUM function.

**2)** Read the calling file as text -- if you can read directly to a line without having to process the entire file - then that would be quicker. There may be some libraries out there that do this. In default Python, I haven't done a huge amount of file i/o other than the basics so I'm not up to speed on all of the most useful things as I typically use SQL for storage purposes, etc...

**3)** With the line in question, split the line text on '=', ie: before the function call to have the arguments, and the function itself.. call it _result

**4)a** IF you have no results then someone called the function without returning anything - odd..

**4)** split _result[ 0 ] on ',' to get each individual argument, and trim whitespace left / right --

**5)** Combine the clean arguments into a list..

**6)** Process the args -- ie: determine the method the developer uses to name their enum values, and see if that style changes from the last argument ( if no map ). If map, then go back n or n*2 elements for the list, then onward from there for the map vars. With maps, map returns are given - the only thing I need to do dynamically is the number and determine if the user has a list arg, or not..

**Note:** There is a very useful and simple mechanism in Python to do a lot of these functions in-line with a single line of code.

All of this is possible, and easy to create in Python. The thing I dislike about this solution is the fact that it requires file i/o -- If your program is executed from another program, and doesn't remain in memory, this means these tasks are always repeated making it less friendly, and more costly...

If the program opens, and remains open, then the cost is more up-front instead of on-going making it not as bad.

Because I use ENUMs in everything, including quick executable scripts which run then close - I don't want to use file i/o..

But, a solution does exist. I'm looking for an alternate.